# How to include static assets dynamically with nuxt generate?

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm working on a static site using Nuxt.js (I target to publish just the result of `nuxt generate`).

The content is generated based on [`asyncData`](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data) by calling a json API.

*I want to grab some files and include them as if they were in the `/static` directory, depending on the API response. How could that be achieved?*

To better illustrate the problem: Let's say there is a list of invoices coming from the API, so in the resulting page I show the invoice info, but I also want to include a download link to it's corresponding file (which I can resolve after knowing the API response).

Maybe this task should be done outside of nuxt.js, after the site generation?

Comment: I don't get ready-to-go solution, but I think you should take a look on nuxt module to do that. https://nuxtjs.org/guide/modules

Comment: I don't really understand the problem. If you have a list of invoices,why can't this list not already include a link to a file,which is situated in the `/static` folder? That would mean you could generate normally and the pages include links to your files. All good... Or do I misunderstand?

Comment: @Merc The list of invoices is dynamic, I call a 3rd party API in the àsyncData` method in order to build it. That list includes the file location (in this case it's a shared drive accessible from the vpn), so the file is not in `/static` yet, I would need to copy it first. The problem is that copy step. Hope it clarify what was the problem

Comment: Puh, if you need to copy your files dynamically from a VPN protected shared drive on each generate, this is gonna require some special tasks, that have nothing to with nuxt.
Where do you publish you app? For example on netlify you could run `nuxt generate && npm run copy` your `copy` task you then have to start a node script which does all the copying and within your nuxt component, you just provide links to the files you are going to copy to `/dist`. I think this would probably be it, but it seems quite tedious and a difficult task. Maybe there are simpler solutions.

Comment: Will those files change all the time over time? If so I would rather try to make that share drive folder public and link directly to those files. Or if they stay the same, I would download the manually into the static folder.
Messing around with node copying your files from a vpn protected shared drive folder into your `/dist` folder seems a bit overkill.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I agree that this scenario is too specific for my needs, and I don't expect nuxt to address all these requeriments. The `nuxt generate && npm run copy` approach is good enough. Reading the docs now, I guess another alternative is to write a custom `buildModule`. I am not working on this project anymore, but I will fiddle with custom modules if I have some spare time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`static` folder is not intended to be like that and it's not intended that the files will change. It's just a way to inject those files into the root directory `dist`. So if it's dynamic either you don't use `static` or you first copy all your files in `static` using a command before `nuxt generate`.

https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/static/